# Updated app has saved the original data

Tags: iphone

What is the trick that some apps after update keep original data saved before update for example scores or settings. I would like to use it with pList, but have not found how yet.

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no trick. Anything you save to user defaults or your app's documents directory will be preserved in an update.

Answer (score 0):

Just save it to a file in your "Documents" folder, or use NSUserPreferences.

Both are retained across updates.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to handle it correctly, but I could be wrong.